# & sign in LinkLabel Text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, access-keys

I want to display the text `a&b` in my `LinkLabel.Text`.

```
linkLabel1.Text = "a&b";
```

This displays:

> ab

If I change the code to:

```
 linkLabel1.Text = "a&&b";
```

one `&` sign will show.

> a&b

Is this the correct way to print one ampersand?

Comment: _"Is it a bug?"_ - yes, you are the first person to use an ampersand on a form control. I would send a mail to Microsoft.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Some of us will try to help.

Comment: @NeilMoss I don't know if that comment was directed at me, but if you look at my profile you see I'm eager to help - those that show research effort. @ Soner, you're welcome. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` is a shortcut key from winforms controls.

`"a&b"` means; shortcut key for <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>

Check out: [`Create Access Keys for Windows Forms Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az5a73z1.aspx)

> To include an ampersand in a caption without creating an access key,
>   include two ampersands (&&). A single ampersand is displayed in the
>   caption and no characters are underlined.

```
// Set the letter "P" as an access key.
button1.Text = "&Print";
```

Also I found [`Label.UseMnemonic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.usemnemonic.aspx) property.

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the control interprets an
>   ampersand character (&) in the control's Text property to be an access
>   key prefix character.

Comment: +1, I would steal the `alt` button style, but on some other question

Comment: @Habib Thanks. `<kbd>` looks cool always :)

Answer (score 4):

`&` in winform is used for short cut key with Alt. By using double `&&` you are escaping the shortcut key modifier.

So for `"a&b"` , shortcut/hot key would be: `alt+b`

You may see: [How to: Create Access Keys for Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az5a73z1.aspx)

> Set the Text property to a string that includes an ampersand (&)
>   before the letter that will be the shortcut.

Comment: +1 for fastest right answer....

Answer (score 1):

`&` is a special char in control text properties. It's used for instance to underline context menu hotkeys. For instance `&File` will get you the word File with the F underlined

Answer (score 1):

Use `UseMnemonic` property.

You can get it over here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.usemnemonic.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To extend on Freelancer's answer - yes, set the `UseMnemonic` property of your label to `true`, and this will show a&b as `a&b`, rather than ab̲

However, this will stop you from assigning an Alt+ shortcut, as described in other answers.